# Display of bad cross-referenced Section headers in PDfs exported by org-mode

Tags: org-mode

Take an example when I attempt to cross-reference a header in org-mode that does not exist. When I export an org file to LaTeX, it does not generate a `ref`, but instead a `texttt`. For example:

```
* Foo

Detail X is in Section [[Bar]]. Detail Y is in Section [[Baz]].

* Bar
```

This exports to:

```
\section{Foo}
\label{sec-1}

Detail X is in Section \ref{sec-2}. Detail Y is in Section \texttt{Baz}.
\section{Bar}
\label{sec-2}
```

When I am using the `:export:` and `:noexport` tags to export only parts of my org document, any "bad" cross-refs (i.e. that reference a non-exported heading) are transmored into verbatim with `texttt`. When those headings are long, the resulting bad cross ref looking ugly.

Question: can I instead tell org-mode just simply export `\texttt{??}` for a bad cross-referenced heading? This would make it look consistent with broken bibtex citations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this variable out:

`org-latex-link-with-unknown-path-format` is a variable defined in `ox-latex.el`.
Its value is `\\texttt{%s}`

Documentation:
Format string for links with unknown path type.

Comment: Perfect, I copied this in to my ~/.emacs and overwrote it with  `\\texttt{??}`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As already said, you can configure the variable to sthing other than \texttt.
What I use:

```
(setq org-latex-link-with-unknown-path-format "\\colorbox{red}{%s}")
```